# Unable to retrieve response with HttpClient in C# script

Tags: c#, postman, dotnet-httpclient

I send a serialized json object in the body of a POST request that contains the user and password. It's required that I get the authorization Bearer token in the response in order to make a follow-up call. The response is json as well.

Postman works flawlessly.

```
string url  = baseUrl + "/Login/GetToken";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
CredObject userInfo = new CredObject();

userInfo.user = tokenUser;
userInfo.password = tokenPwd;
                
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo);                              
var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;               
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The exception states

> One or more errors occurred
>
> Class:System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1

Comment: please provide more of the exception stacktrace

Comment: Try `await DoAnythingAsync()` instead of `DoAnythingAsync().Result` when using the async version of the methods. .Result will block the calling thread until the operation is completed. Maybe this causes your exception?

Comment: Thanks @johnmoarr I will try that and update here w/full stacktrace